# Button animation setDuration() doesn't work

Tags: android, xamarin, android-animation

I am new to Xamarin and I want to animate a Button in my Android app. When the Button gets clicked it should fade out within 0,5 sec.
I wrote this code:

```
animButton.Click += (sender, e) => 
{ 
    animButton.Animate().AlphaBy(-1.0f).SetDuration(500).Start();
};
```

Well the Button does disappear but instantly.
I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you didn't disable animations in developer options in the phone settings. It took me a whole day to realize that's why my animations happen instantly.